# Zend framework 2 Characters converted to unreadable format

Tags: encoding, zend-framework2, character

I have googled every related resource and cant seem to figure this one out. My database is in utf8_unicode_ci collation, hence I saved all the source files in UTF8 format. But when the data is returned to the view file, it gets distorted.

However, when I hard code texts in the model file and the view files, with the same language that is used in the database, it displays the text without any glitches. So its definitely not a problem with my source file encoding type. I get a the distorted text as such:

> †Þ§Þ‡Þ¨Þ‡Þ¬Þ†Þª Þ†Þ¬Þ‰Þ°Þ•Þ¬Þ‡Þ¨'

Sorry but I am a complete newbie to MMVC and Zend. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the [configuration of your `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable). This should include the diver options to set the DB to UTF8 naming convention:

```
<?php
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Another potential source of error is the PHP-Webserver. Webservers do have the option to sent out the charset-header to basically overwrite everything you do. To counter this, you gotta set the header inside your PHP-Script:

```
//index.php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

With this every browser should render your stuff correctly. But just to make things overall complete, you can also set the meta-tag to your HTML-Template:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

or the HTML5 equivalent

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

With this, you can be pretty sure that your wanted charset will be rendered ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Turns out i forgot to include the driver options line in the global.php file. This worked like a charm! :)